# Modified Fibonacci in C

Tags: c, dynamic-programming, fibonacci

I need to generate a modified Fibonacci series and it must be completely dynamic. Here f0 and f1 will be given, i.e f0=1 and f1=3 after generating the series. I should print the resulting value at a particular index.

Ex: f0 = 1, f1 = 3, testcase(n) = 3 (This can change not a particular value)

t1 = 4 t2 = 8 t3 = 11 and so on. Series should be generated for 11 elements by adding current element and previous element using: f[i] = f[i-1] + f[i-2]

It can be represented as:

```
0=>1
1=>3
2=>4
3=>7
4=>11
5=>18
6=>29
7=>47
8=>76
9=>123
10=>199
11=>322
```

I should print the values at indices 4,8 and 11 (which must be the output of my program), i.e. `11 76 322`.

Input Format:

f0,f1 and n (where n is the no of indices)

where ti=[t1,t2,....tn-1] (which specifies the index for R-Fibonacci series).

Output Format:
Print the values from the R-fibonacci series based on the given indices.

Sample Input:
    1 3 3 4 8 11

Sample Output:
    11 76 322

I have the code that generates the Fibonacci series for the above program but I want to display the value at 4,8,11 indices. Here is the code:

```
int fib(int n)
{
    int f[n+1];
    int i;
    f[0]=1;
    f[1]=3;
    for(i=2;i<=n;i++)
    {
       f[i]=f[i-1]+f[i-2];
    }
    return f[n];
}

int main()
{
   int n=11
   printf("%d ",fib(n));
   getchar();
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: OT but the interesting (to me) fact about this series is that each term `n` becomes increasingly close to `Φ**n`. (`Φ` the Golden Ratio).

Comment: Yes, but is there a way where I can create a new array and map the values generated in the series as the arrays index values? @WeatherVane

Comment: @WeatherVane As far as I know the values will be of golden ratio, as the values will be exponentially far from one other

Comment: You could define the array in `main` as pass it as a function argument.

Comment: @WeatherVane could you tell me how ? Cuz, I'm trying to get it work from past 2 hours or so. I am now generating the series. But I am not able to extract the values that are at 4,8 and 11th index

Comment: IIUC your question isn't really about fibonacci at all; it's about how to share an array between two functions. You should ask about what you really need to know.

Comment: Also your code is missing `#include <stdio.h>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this? The array is defined in `main` and passed to the function as an argument. The function fills in the array, returns nothing, and then in `main` you can print the elements you want.

You will need a loop to do that, with another dynamic array holding the indices you are asked to print.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void fib(int n, int *f)
{
    int i;
    f[0] = 1;
    f[1] = 3;
    for(i = 2; i <= n; i++)
    {
       f[i] = f[i-1] + f[i-2];
    }
}

int main()
{
   int n = 11;
   int f[n+1];
   fib(n, f);
   printf("%d ", f[8]);
   printf("%d ", f[11]);
   printf("\n");
   getchar();
   return 0;
}
```

Program output:

```
76 322
```

I will leave you some code to write, but suppose you make a dynamic array of the index values required, such as

```
int index[m];
index[0] = 4;
index[1] = 8;
index[2] = 11;
```

you can print the series term with such as

```
printf("%d ", f[ index[i] ]);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot !!. It helped me

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, this question really has little to do with fibonacci and is about scope in C. You are declaring and defining an array in a function, `fib`, and filling it within that function (and returning a single element value). What you want is to have access to the entire array from the caller.

A straightforward way of doing this is to declare the array in the calling method, and pass a pointer to it to the `fib` function:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int fib(int f[], int n)
{
    int i;
    f[0]=1;
    f[1]=3;
    for(i=2;i<=n;i++)
    {
       f[i]=f[i-1]+f[i-2];
    }
    return f[n];
}

int main()
{
   int n=11;
   int f[12];
   fib(f, n);
   printf("%d ", f[4]);
   printf("%d ", f[8]);
   printf("%d ", f[11]);
   getchar();
   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a code to generate a set of fibonacci numbers less than a given number N using recursive algorithm :

```
#include<stdio.h>
int fibo(int n)
{
    if(n<2)
        return n;
    else
        return (fibo(n-1)+fibo(n-2));
}
void main()
{
    int n,i;
    printf("\n Enter number : ");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    printf("\n Fibonacci series is : ");
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
        printf("\n %d",fibo(i));
}
```